# How to get HashTable with Selenium ExecuteScript function

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

with Selenium WebDriver, to get all html attributes at once for a Tag in C#, I do this

```
ReadOnlyCollection<object> HtmlAttributes = (ReadOnlyCollection<object>)((IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("var s = []; var attrs = arguments[0].attributes; for (var l = 0; l < attrs.length; ++l) { var a = attrs[l]; s.push(a.name + ':' + a.value); } ; return s;", ele);
```

But with this JavaScript code, I got an array with values :

```
HtmlAttributes[index] = "HtmlAttribute:Value".
```

Is it possible to get an hashtable? For example:

```
HtmlAttributes[HtmlAttribute] = "Value"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why wouldn't the following work?

```
// Putting this all on one line would work just fine; I'm
// breaking it out here for readability.
string script = 
    @"var s = {};
      var attrs = arguments[0].attributes;
      for (var index = 0; index < attrs.length; ++index) {
        var a = attrs[index];
        s[a.name] = a.value;
      }
      return s;";

// Direct casting would work in a single line as well.
// Again, using the "as" operator and multiple lines for
// readability.
// ASSUMPTIONS: "driver" is a valid IWebDriver object, and
// "element" is a valid IWebElement object found using FindElement.
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
Dictionary<string, object> attributes = executor.ExecuteScript(script, element) as Dictionary<string, object>;
```

Now, there are a couple of caveats to this. The first is that serializer from `ExecuteScript` does not do a good job recursing overly complex objects. That means that if an attribute has an object as its value, this may not work as well as you'd like. As an example, I wouldn't try to serialize a jQuery object back from JavaScript. The other caveat is that the return type will be `Dictionary<string, object>`. If you want to create a `Hashtable`, or convert the values to strings, you'll have to convert those values yourself after getting the values from JavaScript.